# How can I drop my cluster?

Tags: sql, oracle

A few hours ago, I execute my procedure that print my consistent gets and time of a set of processes. I obtained 1.5 seconds.

Now I drop all my tables and my cluster also and I execute my procedure again but now I obtained 50 seconds. I've done this several times and also I obtain the same (50 seconds) I dont know what could be happening

Please HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe oracle is trying to use the old statistics for to optimize your queries, look for example here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/stats.htm#i41282

you should drop the statistic so that it will rebuild it again with the new data:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_STATS.DELETE_TABLE_STATS('YOURSCHEMA','YOURTABLE');
END;
```

Comment: a schema is the logical group in oracle that holds your tables, like, but not the same, a DB instance.

Comment: And how can I know what's 'YOURCHEMA' ?

Comment: select owner as schema_name, table_name 
from all_tables 
where table_name like 'YOURTABLE_NAME';